# Não consigo salvar foto no banco

Tags: java, html, banco-de-dados, imagem

Estou criando uma aplicaçao web que faz o cadastro de funcionários,e nesse cadastro há uma opção de fazer upload de foto para vincular ao perfil, porem ao cadastrar chega null no banco. Alguém pode me ajudar?

**Essa é minha entidade:**

```
public class Agente extends Model{
@Required
@Expose
public String nome;
@Required
public String funcao;
@Required
@MinSize(6)
public String login;
@MinSize(6)
@MaxSize(15)
public String senha;
@Required
@Email
public String email;
public Blob foto;


@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public Status status;

public Agente() {
    status = Status.ATIVO;
}

}
```

**O meu controller de cadastro:**

```
public static void cadastrarFuncionarios(@Valid Agente funcionario, String senha) throws Exception {

    Agente funcionarioBanco = Agente.find("email = ? or login = ?", funcionario.email, funcionario.login).first();

    if (funcionario.id == null) {
        if (funcionarioBanco != null && funcionarioBanco.id != funcionarioBanco.id && funcionarioBanco.foto == null) {
            validation.addError("funcionario.email", "E-mail já existente");
            validation.addError("funcionario.login", "Usuário já existente");
            validation.addError("funcionario.foto", "Imagem já cadastrada");
        }
        if (validation.hasErrors() || !funcionario.senha.equals(senha)) {
            validation.addError("funcionario.senha", "Senha não corresponde");
            params.flash();
            validation.keep();
            form();
        }
        if (funcionario.foto == null && funcionario.id != null) {
            Agente n = Agente.findById(funcionario.id);

            if (n.foto.exists()) {
                funcionario.foto = n.foto;
            }
        }
        funcionario.senha = Crypto.passwordHash(senha);
        validation.valid("cadastrado com sucesso");
        funcionario.save();
        session.get("usuarioLogado");
        listarFuncionarios(null);
    }
}
```

**e a div reponsavel por capturar a imagem no html:**

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label>Adicionar foto do perfil:</label> <input type="file" name="funcionario.foto" class="form-control">
</div>
```

**saida:**

> @76gk5ei72
>       funcionarios.pulpitrock.jpg action not found
>
> ```
> Action not found
> Action funcionarios.pulpitrock.jpg could not be found. Error raised is Controller controllers.funcionarios.pulpitrock not found
>
> play.exceptions.ActionNotFoundException: Action funcionarios.pulpitrock.jpg not found     at
> ```
>
> play.mvc.ActionInvoker.getActionMethod(ActionInvoker.java:578)    at
>   play.mvc.ActionInvoker.resolve(ActionInvoker.java:84)     at
>   Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
>       Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Controller controllers.funcionarios.pulpitrock not found  ... 3 more

Comment: Já tentou usar um try catch para verificar o que acontece?

Comment: ele exibe isso: Action funcionarios.pulpitrock.jpg could not be found. Error raised is Controller controllers.funcionarios.pulpitrock not found

Comment: Adicione esse atributo ao seu form `enctype="multipart/form-data"` e na sua controller o arquivo não virá como atributo da sua model ele vai estar no contexto da requisição... você vai ter que salvar em um diretório do servidor ou o blob do arquivo no banco.